# ActiveRecord: Scope to get parents with no children created at a specific date

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I want to get all parent records with **no** records created at a specific date on a one-to-many relation in Rails 4 with ActiveRecord and Postgres as database.

Migrations:

```
class CreateParents < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    enable_extension 'pgcrypto' unless extension_enabled?('pgcrypto')

    create_table :parents, id: :uuid, default: 'gen_random_uuid()' do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.timestamps null: false
    end
end

class CreateChilds < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :childs, id: false do |t|
      t.uuid :parent_id, null: false
      t.date :created_at, null: false
      t.string :name
    end

    add_foreign_key :childs, :parents
    add_index :childs, [:parent_id, :created_at], :unique => true
  end
end
```

Models:

```
class Parent < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :childs
end

class Child < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :parent
end
```

Now I want to get all parents with no child at a specific date with a scope:

```
class Parent < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :childs

  def self.with_no_childs_created_at(date)
    ...
  end
end
```

Can anybody help me? I'm going really crazy with this. I tried a lot things with `.includes`, `.references`, `.where`, `.not`, `.joins` etc. but I don't get it.

---

**Update 1**

One suggested solution looked likes this:

```
def self.with_no_stats_created_at(date)
  joins(:childs).where.not(childs: {created_at: date})
end
```

But this only works if the parent has already a child created in the past. The SQL should demonstrate the problem:

```
SELECT "parents".*
FROM "parents"
INNER JOIN "childs" ON "childs"."parent_id" = "parents"."id"
WHERE ("childs"."created_at" != $1)  [["created_at", "2016-04-19"]]
```

---

**Update 2**

This solved the problem (suggested by @Ilya):

```
def self.with_no_childs_created_at(date)
  preload(:childs).select {|p| p.childs.all? {|c| c.created_at != date }}
end
```

Comment: The concept of "parents with no children" is so strange that I am laughing since I read your title! Thanks!

Comment: Children with no parents are a common thing, unfortunately. But never heard about the opposite till now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can preload childs to avoid `N+1` queries and process it like array:

```
def self.with_no_childs_created_at(date)
  preload(:childs).select {|p| p.childs.all? {|c| c.created_at != date }}
end
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response! But your solution only works if the parent has already a child created in the past.

Comment: @JohnDoe what exactly behavior you expect? Can you write an instance?

Comment: Short example – three parent records: The first has no child, the second has one child created yesterday and the third has one child created today. I want to get the first and the second parent with `Parent.with_no_childs_created_at(Date.today)`.

Comment: Thank you so much! This solved my problem and saved my day :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it entirely in the database, which is faster most of the time:

```
scope :without_children_at(date) = {
  joins(:childs).where("DATE(created_at) != DATE(?)", date)
}
```